# Python: from list group by elements after a specific trigger element

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list like

```
a=['a',2,'[abcd]','bb',4,5,'kk','[efgh]',6,7,'no','[ijkl]',4,5,'lo']
```

So here we want group by after each '[]'

so the expected one would be

```
[['a',2],{'abcd': ['bb',4,5,'kk']},{'efgh': [6,7,'no']},{'ijkl': [4,5,'lo']}]
```

Any help would be appriciable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby 

a=['a',2,'[abcd]','bb',4,5,'kk','[efgh]',6,7,'no','[ijkl]',4,5,'lo']

def group_by_tag(li):
    def tag_counter(x):
        if isinstance(x, str) and x.startswith('[') and x.endswith(']'):
            tag_counter.cnt += 1
        return tag_counter.cnt
    tag_counter.cnt = 0
    
    return groupby(li, key=tag_counter)
```

Which you can use to make a list of tuples for each segment partitioned by the `[tag]`:

```
>>> x=[(k,list(l)) for k, l in group_by_tag(a)]
>>> x
[(0, ['a', 2]), (1, ['[abcd]', 'bb', 4, 5, 'kk']), (2, ['[efgh]', 6, 7, 'no']), (3, ['[ijkl]', 4, 5, 'lo'])]
```

And then create your desired mixed-type list from that:

```
>>> [v if k==0 else {v[0].strip('[]'):v[1:]} for k,v in x]
[['a', 2], {'abcd': ['bb', 4, 5, 'kk']}, {'efgh': [6, 7, 'no']}, {'ijkl': [4, 5, 'lo']}]
```

But consider that it is usually better to have a list of the same type of object to make processing that list easier.

If you want that, you could do:

```
>>> [{'no_tag':v} if k==0 else {v[0].strip('[]'):v[1:]} for k,v in x]
[{'no_tag': ['a', 2]}, {'abcd': ['bb', 4, 5, 'kk']}, {'efgh': [6, 7, 'no']}, {'ijkl': [4, 5, 'lo']}]
```

Answer (score -1):

By "=>" I assume you want a dictionary if there is a preceding keyword and key be the word enclosed within the square brackets (if that's not what you intended feel free to comment and I'll edit this post)

```py
import re

def sort(iterable):
    result = {}
    governing_match = None
    for each in list(iterable):
        match = re.findall(r"\[.{1,}\]", str(each))
        if len(match) > 0:
            governing_match = match[0][1:-1]
            result[governing_match] = []
            continue
        result[governing_match].append(each)
    return result


a=['[foo]', 'a' , 2 ,'[abcd]','bb',4,5,'kk','[efgh]',6,7,'no','[ijkl]',4,5,'lo']
for (k, v) in sort(a).items():
    print(f"{k} : {v}")
```

Result :

```
foo : ['a', 2]
abcd : ['bb', 4, 5, 'kk']
efgh : [6, 7, 'no']
ijkl : [4, 5, 'lo']
```

The limitation of this is that every sequence should start with an element that is enclosed within square brackets.

Answer (score -2):

You can use pairwise for that:

```
from itertools import pairwise

a=['a',2,'[abcd]','bb',4,5,'kk','[efgh]',6,7,'no','[ijkl]',4,5,'lo']

bracket_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if isinstance(x, str)
                   and x.startswith('[') and x.endswith(']')]
bracket_indices.append(len(a))

output = [a[:bracket_indices[0]]]  # First item is special cased
output.extend({a[i][1:-1]: a[i+1:j]} for i, j in pairwise(bracket_indices))
```

Comment: Broken with `a=['[abcd]','bb',4,5,'kk','[efgh]',6,7,'no','[ijkl]',4,5,'lo']`

Comment: @dawg no it's not, it gives an empty list at first, showing there's no non-bracket items beforehand -> `[[], {'abcd': ['bb', 4, 5, 'kk']}, {'efgh': [6, 7, 'no']}, {'ijkl': [4, 5, 'lo']}]`

Comment: @dawg your output doesn't make sense, my code creates dictionaries. Are you sure you're running my code?